# Time Limitation for matters before the UK committee of privileges

Tags: united-kingdom, parliament

can a matter before the committee of privileges in one parliamentary term move into a new parliamentary term?

Answer (score 1):

All parliamentary business lapses at the end of a Parliament, including anything a committee is working on. As a result, it's not uncommon for committees to rush out a report shortly before Parliament is dissolved ahead of an election.

However, there is nothing to stop a committee picking up or continuing the work of a previous committee, as committees are free to investigate any matter they like that is within their remit.